# NGinx rewrite rules and post parameters

Tags: nginx, ajax, codeigniter

I have a website, using CodeIgniter, and running under NGinx.

I used [these rewrite rules](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-nginx-rewrite-rules/) to cleanup the URL, and remove the index.php from the URL.

Unfortunately, I have a problem with AJAX queries which send POST arguments to the controller, as the controller receives no argument.

Using Firebug Lite, I can see that I give the correct POST parameters to the controller, but when I print them in the controller, nothing is printed.

I guess it is from the rewrite rules, which don't seem to pass the parameters along the URL, but I don't know how to fix that.

Would anyone have an idea?

Here are the rewrite rules, might be easier to have them here instead of on the other site:

```
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
{
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
}

# canonicalize codeigniter url end points
# if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
if ($request_uri ~* ^(/welcome(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
{
    rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
}

# removes trailing "index" from all controllers
if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
}

# removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
if (!-d $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

# removes access to "system" folder, also allows a "System.php" controller
if ($request_uri ~* ^/system)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}

# unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your config is ugly. Please, see: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

i think, using rewrite (as in apache) does not forward post data,
instead try to configure nginx as front proxy